# Resolving rails image url in webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, assets, resolve, webpacker

I have a Rails 5 app using the `webpacker` gem. I would like to access the image urls with the hash from the rails asset compilation appended to the end of their file names.

here is my `/config/webpacker.yml` file

```
# Note: You must restart bin/webpack-dev-server for changes to take effect

default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_output_path: packs
  resolved_paths: ['app/assets/images']

  extensions:
    - .coffee
    - .erb
    - .js
    - .jsx
    - .ts
    - .vue
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default

  dev_server:
    host: 0.0.0.0
    port: 8080
    https: false

test:
  <<: *default

  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default
```

And I am attempting to import an image via `import logo from '../logo.jpg';`

I receive this error:

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../logo.jpg' in '/Users/macusername/Documents/work/railsapp/app/javascript/components'`

Comment: Any solution for this?